# How to get multiple records with reading json file in asp.net core api

Tags: json, asp.net-core

There is a JSON file on My Asp.net core APi project.

I want this API to grab that file and then read all the records within that file so it is ready to display and available for requests.

For example I  have list of employees in my employee.json file:

```
   {
  "EmployeeList": [
    {
      "EmpId": 1,
      "EmpName": "Krish",
      "EmpCode": 1001,
      "JoiningDate": "12/07/2021",
      "DeptId": 1,
      "DesgId": 2
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 2,
      "EmpName": "Prish",
      "EmpCode": 1002,
      "JoiningDate": "17/02/2021",
      "DeptId": 3,
      "DesgId": 1
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 3,
      "EmpName": "Krishna",
      "EmpCode": 1003,
      "JoiningDate": "12/04/2020",
      "DeptId": 2,
      "DesgId": 2
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 4,
      "EmpName": "Ram",
      "EmpCode": 1004,
      "JoiningDate": "12/07/2021",
      "DeptId": 1,
      "DesgId": 2
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 5,
      "EmpName": "Rahul",
      "EmpCode": 1005,
      "JoiningDate": "10/07/2021",
      "DeptId": 3,
      "DesgId": 2
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 6,
      "EmpName": "Raja",
      "EmpCode": 1006,
      "JoiningDate": "12/01/2021",
      "DeptId": 1,
      "DesgId": 2
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 7,
      "EmpName": "Hiya",
      "EmpCode": 1007,
      "JoiningDate": "2/07/2021",
      "DeptId": 3,
      "DesgId": 2
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 8,
      "EmpName": "Riya",
      "EmpCode": 1008,
      "JoiningDate": "2/05/2021",
      "DeptId": 1,
      "DesgId": 3
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 9,
      "EmpName": "Sheela",
      "EmpCode": 1009,
      "JoiningDate": "12/10/2021",
      "DeptId": 1,
      "DesgId": 2
    },
    {
      "EmpId": 10,
      "EmpName": "Komal",
      "EmpCode": 1010,
      "JoiningDate": "12/01/2021",
      "DeptId": 1,
      "DesgId": 1
    }
  ]
 
}
```

Model Class Like this:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public List<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeList { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmployeeDetail
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public int EmpCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public int DesgId { get; set; }

    }
```

Note : i dont want use database using json file and module class i need to get multiple records in Controller.
Now My multiple records which i need to execute is

1. Find all Employees's DepartmentId where DesgId=2
2. Find distinct designation (i.e[{1}.{2}])

help me with some steps or code.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, if the file is storing inside your web application, I suggest you could try to use `IWebHostEnvironment` to get the path and then use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` to read the json content.

Then you could use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize the json's content to a list.

After converting to the list, you could use LINQ to put some selector to that List.

More details, you could refer to below example codes:

Model class:

```
    public class Employee 
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public int EmpCode { get; set; }
        public string JoiningDate { get; set; }
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public int DesgId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller's codes:

```
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger , IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;

        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var rootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath; //get the root path

        var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "employee.json"); //combine the root path with that of our json file inside mydata directory

        var jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullPath); //read all the content inside the file


        Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonData);

        var  result =  root.EmployeeList.Where(x => x.DeptId == 2).ToList() ;
       return result ;}
```

Result:
[image]